# Ghostscript Arabic entry

Tags: fonts, arabic, ghostscript

How to enter Arabic text and get it rendered in Ghostscript 9.14 (under Windows XP)?

e.g.
Although Arial font has Arabic glyphs,
the following Ghostscript code does not work.

```
/Arial 200 selectfont
0 0 moveto
.5 setgray
(جوستسكربت عربى!) show
showpage

-
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to read the PostScript Language Reference Manual quite extensively in order to embed a TrueType font as a CIDFont, or create a Type 0 font, in order to write Arabic script.

In addition, Arial is a TrueType font (or collection) and the PostScript specification doesn't permit the use of TrueType fonts. Ghostscript has extensions which will allow it to use TrueType fonts as Fonts and CIDFonts. It **may** be that you can get away with using these extensions, though its very likely that you will have to use Unicode code points or something.

Basically there is no simple answer to your question, if you want to do this you have a lot of research ahead of you.

You should start by reading the PostScript Language Reference Manual so that you fully understand Fonts, Font Types, Encoding arrays and CharString dictionaries, CIDFonts, CMaps and CIDSystemInfo dictionaries. If you would prefer to use Ghostscript's extensions for handling TrueType fonts then you need to read the Ghostscript documentation, eg /ghostpdl/gs/doc/Language.htm#DecodingResources.

Comment: Hi from the orginal questioner